# Window scroll events have stopped firing on all implementations across entire domain

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

This is a strange problem I'm hoping to find some insight on. 
My personal [page](https://www.philandrews.io/blog) has a number of scroll listeners on it. The nav bar hides and unhides on scroll, images are lazy loaded, etc. I listen to scrolls across the entire domain. I just noticed that they have all stopped working when I went to put in a new scroll listener on a subpage. I can't get any scroll event to fire:

- `window.addEventListener` does nothing
- `onScroll` attached to a div does nothing
- `react-lazyload` does nothing
- `react-event-listener` does nothing

Basic scroll listener implementation:

```
constructor() {
    super()

    this.handleScroll = this.handleScroll.bind(this)
    this.setColorsForState = this.setColorsForState.bind(this)
}

componentWillMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', _.throttle(this.handleScroll, 150))
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeListener('scroll', _.throttle(this.handleScroll, 150))
}


handleScroll(event) {
   console.log('scrolling')
}
```

It was working perfectly fine for months.

This isn't browser specific, it doesn't fire in any browser.

Listeners listening for `resize` **do** work.

What, on earth, could be blocking an event from firing across an entire domain? Any suggestions on where to start would be a huge help. I've already gone back and started removing recent additions to see where the problem might lie but nothing has worked yet. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The link you provided points to a dead page.

Comment: @AlienBishop Was missing a character. All fixed

Comment: Adding the event on the body works fine:
document.body.addEventListener("scroll", function(){console.log("scrolling!!!")})

Comment: @ShacharW Nice, yes it does. That's a start. I can at least cobble something together now. But those modules, still gotta figure that out.

Comment: It doesn't work in your components because the scroll is on the body but you added the event on the window.
If the scroll was on the html tag, then your code would work.

Comment: It's not just the listeners I wrote. It's all the libraries mentioned. And they were working before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I found the cause.

You have this css rule on your body/html tags:

```
body, html {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Guess it is for hiding the default scrollbar and using your own. When you un-check it in your browser the scrolling event would come back to life.

Also noted that un-checking this rule `height: 100%!important;` would bring the scrollbar back and the events as well.

Comment: Thanks dude, you saved me